# axios.interceptors.request.use() How to handle x-www-form-urlencoded with qs?

Tags: javascript, axios

I saw a solution on github, but it didn't work:

```js
import qs from 'qs';

axios.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
  if (request.data && request.headers['Content-Type'] === 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') {
      request.data = qs.stringify(request.data);
  }
  return request;
});
```

What I need is also this effect. How can I correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code and now it works, Is it appropriate to write like this?

```js
axios.interceptors.request.use((request) => {
  if (request.data && request.headers[request.method]['Content-Type'] === 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') {
    request.data = qs.stringify(request.data)
  }
  return request
})
```